# List FTP Contents in UITableView for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, ftp

I've been looking all over the internet for a simple guide that shows me how to list the contents of an FTP dir in a UITableView and I can't find anything! I've been pushed strongly towards the "SimpleFTP" iOS sample project by Apple - but that's far to old now and the code is more old-school C then Objective C.

Comment: **SimpleFTPSample** is still maintained by Apple so its pretty much the official solution (Revision history last updated on 2013-04-12). "Old school" is often better, imho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this: **[WhiteRaccoon iOS FTP](https://github.com/valentinradu/WhiteRaccoon)** and [get file list section](https://github.com/valentinradu/WhiteRaccoon#list-directory-contents)

> ```
> NSMutableArray* dataSource = [NSMutableArray array];
> for (NSDictionary * file in listDir.filesInfo) { [dataSource addObject:[file objectForKey:(id)kCFFTPResourceName]]  }
> ```

In this `for` you can create your array to use as dataSource for UITableView